# phantomjs Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Helvetica Neue" and got font with PostScript name "HelveticaNeue"

Tags: ruby, rspec, phantomjs, osx-mavericks

I'm running rspec tests and they pass fine but I get the following message:

```
phantomjs[25837:507] CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() 
using name "Helvetica Neue" and got font with PostScript name "HelveticaNeue". 
For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
```

How can/should I resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On this [Github issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11418) you can use `brew update && brew reinstall phantomjs` to get the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is an issue with OS X Mavericks

Because I had the latest version anyway, brew upgrade phantomjs did not work for me.

`brew upgrade phantomjs

Error: phantomjs-1.9.2 already installed`

So this worked:

`brew update && brew reinstall phantomjs`

Which installed: `phantomjs-1.9.2.mavericks.bottle.3.tar.gz`

Answer (score 0):

As seen on Github, try to add `2> >(grep -v CoreText 1>&2)` at the end of your command.

*Source: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11418#issuecomment-30103255*

So if you run CasperJS (l usually with `casperjs test tests/casper/login.js`. It must be `casperjs test tests/casper/login.js 2> >(grep -v CoreText 1>&2)`